# VBA: Data entry into combobox works, but command button gives "Invalid property value" error

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a userform with 3 comboboxes and a command button that, when clicked, puts the entered values into a sheet. I have MatchRequired set to True for all 3 so that other values can't be entered in.

My problem is that I can get past each combobox with no problems as there aren't any inaccuracies. However when I click the command button the Invalid Property Value error comes up. Also - the entry still gets added to the sheet, even with the error. What gives?

I'm loading the combobox options from different columns on that same sheet. Here's the code I have for the command button:

```
Private Sub cmdAddClass_Click()

Dim RowCount As Long

RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.cboGrade.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.cboUnits.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.cboQuarter.Value
End With

Me.cboGrade.Value = ""
Me.cboUnits.Value = ""
Me.cboQuarter.Value = ""
Me.cboGrade.SetFocus

End Sub
```

New here, so thank you for any and all help.

Comment: on what line do you get the error?

Comment: The error was with on the second to last line -
Me.cboGrade.SetFocus

I wanted to have the form clear when I clicked the command button, and so I added that line, but it turns out that wasn't necessary. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue is:

```
Me.cboGrade.Value = ""
'...
Me.cboGrade.SetFocus
```

You are setting `cboGrade` to blank, which is not a value in the combobox list. Therefore when you set the focus to `cboGrade`, the `MatchRequired` setting  rejects it and issues the `Invalid Property Value` message.  Note that this is not actually a VBA error, it's a message from the form control.

Try removing `Me.cboGrade.SetFocus`